# AVL tree(c++), program keeps on crashing

Tags: c++, rotation, avl-tree

I am working on an exercise in processing an AVL tree. The debugger shows no errors. I ran the program and it is supposed to output an output text file. However the program crashes every time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int key;
    int height;
    node *left, *right;
    node(int k)
    {
        key = k;
        height = 1;
        left = right = 0;
    }
};


void pre_order(node* root)
{
    if(root == 0) return;
    printf("%d", root->key);
    printf(" ");
    pre_order(root->left);
    pre_order(root->right);
}

void in_order(node* root)
{
    in_order(root->left);
    printf("%d", root->key);
    printf(" ");
    in_order(root->right);
}

int height(node* r)
{
    return r ? r->height : 0;
}

void update_height(node* root)
{
    if(root == 0) return;
    int hl = height(root->left), hr = height(root->right);
    root->height = std::max(hl, hr) + 1;
}


node* right_rotate(node* ref_root)
{
    assert(ref_root && ref_root->left);
    node *a = ref_root, *b = ref_root->left;
    a->left = b->right;
    b->right = a;

    update_height(a);
    update_height(b);
    return b;
}

node* left_rotate(node* ref_root)
{
    assert(ref_root && ref_root->right);
    node *c = ref_root, *d = ref_root->right;
    c->right = d->left;
    d->left = c;
    update_height(c);
    update_height(d);
    return d;
}


node* maintain(node* ref_root)
{
    if(ref_root == 0) return ref_root;
    update_height(ref_root);
    node* ret = ref_root;
    if(height(ref_root->left) > height(ref_root->right) + 1)
    {
        node* p = ref_root->left;
        if( height(p->left) < height(p->right) )
            ref_root->left = left_rotate(p);
        ret = right_rotate(ref_root);
    }
    else if(height(ref_root->right) > height(ref_root->left) + 1)
    {
        node* p = ref_root->right;
        if(height(p->right) < height(p->left)){
            ref_root->right = right_rotate(p);
        }
        ret = left_rotate(ref_root);
    }
    return ret;
}


node* insert_key(int key, node* ref_root)
{
    if(ref_root == 0)
    {
        return ref_root = new node(key);
    }
    if(key < ref_root->key){
        node* child = insert_key(key, ref_root->left);
        ref_root->left = child;
        }       
    else if(key > ref_root->key){
        node* child = insert_key(key, ref_root->right);
        ref_root->right = child; 
    }
    else
        assert(0); 

    return maintain(ref_root);
}

vector<node*> minimum(node* T) {
    vector<node*> x;
    node* y = T;
    while (y->left != NULL) {
        x.push_back(y->left);
    }
    return x;
}

node* delete_key(int key, node* ref_root)
{
    if(key < ref_root->key){
        node* child = delete_key(key, ref_root->left);
        ref_root->left = child;
        }
    else if(key > ref_root->key){
        node* child = delete_key(key, ref_root->right);
        ref_root->right = child;
        }
    else
    {
        if(ref_root->left && ref_root->right)
        {
            vector <node*> y = minimum(ref_root->right);
            node* successor = y.back();
            node* sParent = y[y.size()-2];
            ref_root->key = successor->key;
            sParent->left = successor->right;
        }
        else
        {
            if(ref_root->left != NULL){
                ref_root = ref_root->left;
            }
            else if(ref_root->right != NULL){
                ref_root = ref_root->right;
            }
        }
    }

    return maintain(ref_root);
}

int main()
{
    node *root = 0;
    char op[10] = "";
    int k;
    while(true)
    {
        scanf("%s", op);
        if(op[0] == 'E') break;
        switch(op[0])
        {
        case 'A': scanf("%d", &k); root = insert_key(k, root); break; //Insert
        case 'D': scanf("%d", &k); root = delete_key(k, root); break;//Delete
        case 'P': pre_order(root); printf("\n"); break;//preorder
        case 'I': in_order(root); printf("\n"); break;//inorder
        default: assert(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `The debugger shows no errors`  The debugger is used so that *you* can determine what/where are the errors.  It isn't going to say "I know what you wanted to do, here is your mistake".

Comment: What i meant is no errors are shown in the debugger so i am trying to figure out what is wrong

Comment: When your program is running under the debugger, the debugger should give access to the backtrace.  As your program is waiting for input, it could be nice either to explain what is the scenario of the crash or better post a [minimal complete and verifiable code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'd suggest running the program with `gdb` in order to see exactly in which line it's crashing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no check in the `in_order` function that root is not NULL.